# Зациклить последовательную анимацию блоков

Tags: css, jquery, веб-программирование, анимация

Как сделать последовательную анимацию, чтобы после пятого блока опять повторялся первый блок. Каждый блок это отдельный `div` c классом `.working-item`. Наверное надо последовательно добавлять блоку класс Active и потом его же удалять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988629/256824

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEYJRPR может быть так ?

Comment: Вы как-то пытаетесь это реализовать и у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function(elements) {
  var i = -1;
  var className = 'working-item__active';
  if (!elements.length) {
    return false;
  }
  function step() {
    elements.eq(i).removeClass(className);
    if (++i >= elements.length) {
      i = 0;
    };
    elements.eq(i).addClass(className);
    setTimeout(step, 1200);
  }
  step();
}($('#general_process').children()));
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#general_process {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.working-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.number {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.number:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.working-item__active .number {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.working-item__active p {
  color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="general_process">
  <div class="working-item">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <p>Вы оставляете заявку</p>
  </div>
  <div class="working-item">
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <p>Мы выезжаем</p>
  </div>
  <div class="working-item">
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <p>Составляем смету</p>
  </div>
  <div class="working-item">
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <p>Выполняем работу</p>
  </div>
  <div class="working-item">
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <p>Вы принимаете работу и оплачиваете</p>
  </div>
</div>
```